# CS50 check50 gives error even though it works properly

Tags: c, cs50

I am currently doing CS50 course and I am at the Problem Set 3 now.
I believe my code is right but the check50 thing of the course, it always shows this one error always.
I tested it with the examples given in the description of the project and got the correct answers.
Am I missing something?

This is my code :

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)
{
    bool check = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
    {
        if (strcmp(candidates[j].name, name) == 0)
        {
            candidates[j].votes = candidates[j].votes + 1;
            check = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return check;
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    int count = 0;
    int equal_count = 0;
    string s;
    for (int k = 0; k < candidate_count - 1; k++)
    {
        if (candidates[k].votes > candidates[k + 1].votes)
        {
            count = candidates[k].votes;
        }
        else if (candidates[k + 1].votes > candidates[k].votes)
        {
            count = candidates[k + 1].votes;
        }
        else
        {
            equal_count = candidates[k + 1].votes;
        }
    }
    if (equal_count > count)
    {
        count = equal_count;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
    {
        if (candidates[j].votes == count)
        {
            s = candidates[j].name;
            printf("%s\n", s);
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

And I got this exact answer that was in the description:

```
$ ./plurality Alice Bob Charlie
Number of voters: 4
Vote: Alice
Vote: Bob
Vote: Charlie
Vote: Alice
Alice
```

But this is what I get when I use check50

```
:) plurality.c exists
:) plurality compiles
:) vote returns true when given name of first candidate
:) vote returns true when given name of middle candidate
:) vote returns true when given name of last candidate
:) vote returns false when given name of invalid candidate
:) vote produces correct counts when all votes are zero
:) vote produces correct counts after some have already voted
:) vote leaves vote counts unchanged when voting for invalid candidate
:( print_winner identifies Alice as winner of election
    print_winner function did not print winner of election
:) print_winner identifies Bob as winner of election
:) print_winner identifies Charlie as winner of election
:) print_winner prints multiple winners in case of tie
:) print_winner prints all names when all candidates are tied
```

check50 always shows this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `print_winner` function is not correct – you always check *neighbouring* candidates. But now imagine counts of 3, 1, 2! In your loop you will first discover 3 as maximum of 3 and 1, but then in next loop run detect that 2 is the maximum of 1 and 2 and update `count` accordingly – inappropriately!

Instead you need to find a global maximum – thus compare each value to the maximum found so far. As you require at least one candidate anyway you can safely do as follows:

```
int max = candidates[0].votes;
for(int i = 1; i < candidate_count; ++i)
{
    if(candidates[i].votes > max)
    {
        max = candidates[i].votes;
    }
}
```

Now you can print out safely the candidates with own votes equal to maximum as before.

Side note: `++someVariable` works, too, if applied to struct members, so you could more conveniently write `++candidates[j].votes` (within `vote` function) – or post increment, if you prefer – just as you did for your loop variables. However, if standing alone (i.e. *not* in constructs like `someArray[i++]`) I'd recommend rather pre-increment – not of much relevance in C, but for the case you might ever switch to C++ then note that there these operators can get overloaded for structs/classes and then post-increment indeed can produce a performance overhead. You avoid if you get used to pre-increment right from the start, even if staying in C...